# Accessing image button created in code behind file on aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a image button in code behind file. It has an event imageButton_Click.  I also want to use this image button and event to create an async post back trigger for a update panel in aspx page.amspanel(basically a panel) is loading all images from folder using image button. I am basically trying do partial post back on page and not make amspanel load again when i click a image in amspanel.

Is it possible to do that? Right now it says....Could not find an event named 'imageButton_Click' on associated control 'imageBtn1' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

```
        private void LoadImages()
        {
        var fileIdx = 0;

            foreach (string strfile in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images")))
            {
                fileIdx++;
                ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton() { ID = "imageBtn" + fileIdx };
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(strfile);
                imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/images/" + fi.Name;
                imageButton.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
                imageButton.Style.Add("padding", "5px");
                imageButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
                imageButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageButton_Click);
                AMSPanel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);
                AMSPanel1.Height=Unit.Pixel(860);
                UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger
                {
                    ControlID = imageButton.ID,
                    EventName = "imageButton_Click"
                });


            }
        }
        protected void imageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs fi)
        {

            testimage.ImageUrl = ((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl;

        }



// In aspx file i am doing this.AMSPanel is just a panel control.

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="testimage" runat="server"  />
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<ams:AMSPanel ID="AMSPanel1" CssClass="CustomWidth" runat="server" Width="130px" Height="700px" ScrollBars="Vertical"> 
</ams:AMSPanel>
```

Comment: Have you given it  a name? without a name you may have a job finding it

Comment: yes imagebutton is it's name

Comment: Are you sure? Its not in the code you posted and would explain your problem

Comment: You are not giving the new button a name.  Seriously. Thats why you cant find it

Comment: Which line is saying it cant find it?

Comment: In ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();  i thought i am giving it a name imageButton. The error basically says   "A control with ID 'imageButton' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1' .

Comment: Your code could call it fred thats not its actual name. Thats the name your code knows it as.  See the answers youve been given. If you eant to call it imageButton.. Then you need to tell it thats its name

Comment: Ok i gave a name like one suggested by @HashPsi. now it says "Multiple controls with the same ID were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs"

Comment: Well yes, if you had 100 freds in a room, how would you tell them apart.. They couldnt all have an email of fred@company.com so, why do you expect an app to know which fred if you just keep calling them all fred?

Comment: Thanks for making me understand this concept @BugFinder. love that example of 100 freds :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an ID for the `ImageButton` that is unique within the page and add the trigger to the update panel from the code behind:

```
    // There are many possible strategies for generating IDs unique within the page. 
    //For example, based on an index corresponding to the current file record.
    var fileIdx = 0;
    foreach (string strfile in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images")))
    {
        fileIdx++;
        ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(){ ID = "imageBtn" + fileIdx };
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(strfile);
        imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/images/" + fi.Name;
        imageButton.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
        imageButton.Style.Add("padding", "5px");
        imageButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
        imageButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageButton_Click);
        AMSPanel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);
        AMSPanel1.Height=Unit.Pixel(860);

        UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger { 
                                    ControlID = imageButton.ID
                                  });
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. I probably misled you before with my question. I edited my question for better understanding.I am actually trying  to create asyncpostback trigger in aspx page.

Comment: I actually used your  idea of adding a id to my image button.I now have a new error which i explained in my question.

Comment: You can generate an ID unique for each `ImageButton` and register the triggger from the code behind. See updated answer.

Comment: brilliant idea.although it cannot find event. the error says...."Could not find an event named 'imageButton_Click' on associated control 'imageBtn1' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'." do you think this is access modifiers stopping it from finding it?

Comment: also updated my question according to your idea and new error.

Comment: @avi Since the event handler is specified in `imageButton.Click`, you should be able to remove the setting of `EventName` property when creating the trigger. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

Imagebutton.Name = "some_name_here";

Then you can find it with FindControl("some_name_here") or at least reference it

Comment: thanks. I edited my question again.Now it has a name.But I have a new error which i explained in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to help so please bear with me.

1. The "Panel" does not have DataSource property, compare with ListView which does have.
2. When you click an imageButton, the page refreshes (because its an "input type=image"), then the "Panel" disposes the imageButtons, thus includes the imageButtons_Click even if you have imageButtons_Click in your .cs, I have doubts that aspx cannot call it.
3. I wish to know your real objective in your project because there are 2 suggestions I have in mind with this current topic.

   1. Server page event oriented (pure asp.net):
      [image]
      and my .cs[image]
   2. Or jquery / javascript (no ajax update panel and imageButton_Click server code-behind). First create a listview only.
      [image]
      Then import a jquery library, and do some script like displayed below:
      [image]

*Note: Notice how I used the CssClass="img-btn" than ID="imgBtn" to call a "click" from javascript? simply because the ID's change when rendered in HTML, see image below:
[image]
Which makes that the attribute "class" as more accessible than attribute "ID".

Hopefully these helps. Cheers!